# Time series CNN, trying to use 1,1 input shape

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to do a CNN 1D for time series.

**First issue:**
When trying to use an input shape of [1,1] I get an error:

```
Error: Negative dimension size caused by adding layer average_pooling1d_AveragePooling1D1 with input shape [,0,128]
```

**2nd issue**
I have 2 different arrays (1d) for my data: first array is the input data containing the time series and the 2nd array contains the output data with closed values for a stock.

Something that got me to a few more results was to set the input shape to [6,1].

Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_Conv1D1 (Conv1D)      [null,5,128]              384       
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling1d_AveragePoo [null,4,128]              0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_Conv1D2 (Conv1D)      [null,3,64]               16448     
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling1d_AveragePoo [null,2,64]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv1d_Conv1D3 (Conv1D)      [null,1,16]               2064      
_________________________________________________________________
average_pooling1d_AveragePoo [null,0,16]               0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_Flatten1 (Flatten)   [null,0]                  0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_Dense1 (Dense)         [null,1]                  1         
=================================================================
```

Here training the model got me into issues:

```
const trainX = tf.tensor1d(data.inTime).reshape([100, 6, 1])
```

100 - size of my array
6 - features
1 - 1 unit as output

```
Error: Size(100) must match the product of shape 100,6,1
```

I'm stuck at the training step because I don't know how to train it.
I would prefere to have a [1,1] input shape, to give only 1 time series and to have 1 output from it.

## The model

```
async function buildModel() {
  const model = tf.sequential()

  // settings
  const kernelSize = 2
  const poolSize = [2]

  // tf layers
  model.add(tf.layers.conv1d({
    inputShape: [6, 1],
    kernelSize: kernelSize,
    filters: 128,
    strides: 1,
    useBias: true,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'varianceScaling'
  }))
  model.add(tf.layers.averagePooling1d({poolSize: poolSize, strides: [1]}))

  // 2nd layer
  model.add(tf.layers.conv1d({
    kernelSize: kernelSize,
    filters: 64,
    strides: 1,
    useBias: true,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'varianceScaling'
  }))
  model.add(tf.layers.averagePooling1d({poolSize: poolSize, strides: [1]}))

  model.add(tf.layers.conv1d({
    kernelSize: kernelSize,
    filters: 16,
    strides: 1,
    useBias: true,
    activation: 'relu',
    kernelInitializer: 'varianceScaling'
  }))
  model.add(tf.layers.averagePooling1d({poolSize: poolSize, strides: [1]}))

  model.add(tf.layers.flatten())

  model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    units: 1,
    kernelInitializer: 'VarianceScaling',
    activation: 'linear'
  }))

  // optimizer + learning rate
  const optimizer = tf.train.adam(0.0001)
  model.compile({
    optimizer: optimizer,
    loss: 'meanSquaredError',
    metrics: ['accuracy'],
  })

  return model
}
```

## Training where the error is occurring

```
async function train(model, data) {
  console.log(`MODEL SUMMARY:`)
  model.summary()
  // Train the model
  const epochs = 2
  // train data size, 28, 28, 1
  const trainX = tf.tensor1d(data.inTime).reshape([100, 6, 1])
  const trainY = tf.tensor([data.outClosed], [1, data.size, 1])

  let result = await model.fit(trainX, trainY, {
      epochs: epochs
  })

  print("Loss after last Epoch (" + result.epoch.length + ") is: " + result.history.loss[result.epoch.length-1])
  return result
}
```

Any ideas into how to fix it will be much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe some advice why it's preferred to send as input params multiple time series instead of just one, because that's what I've seen in the majority of examples over the web.

Comment: can you please add the model to your question ?

Comment: yes, adding it right now

Comment: Can you please use stackblitz.com to demonstrate the issue ? It will be easier to spot the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Time series** is a sequence taken at successive equally spaced points in time according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series). The goal of the neural network NN used on time series is to find the pattern between the series of data. Convolutiona Neural Networks CNN are rarely if not never used on this kind of data. Other NN often used are RNN and LSTM. If we are interested in finding a pattern in a series of data, the inputShape can't be [1, 1]; otherwise it will mean finding a pattern on a unique point. It can be done theoretically, but in reality it does not capture the essence of the time series.

The model used here is using CNN with average pooling layer. Of course, a pooling layer cannot be applied on a layer with a pooling size bigger than the shape of the layer thus throwing the error:

> Error: Negative dimension size caused by adding layer average_pooling1d_AveragePooling1D1 with input shape [,0,128]

The last error:

> Error: Size(100) must match the product of shape 100,6,1

indicates a mismatch of the size of the tensors.

100 * 6 * 1 = 600 elements in the tensor (size =600) whereas the input tensor has 100 elements resulting in the error.

Comment: Thank you so much @edkeveked for all of this info. Now it's much more clear to me what to do. What would be a valid input for my Size(100). For example, I attempted to run it with 16,6,1 - 96 elements but that didn't work.

Comment: It won't work since 96 is different from 100. You have to use a combination so that the size matches 100 like [10, 10, 1], [2, 50, 1], [2, 25, 2], etc... But bear in mind that it will impact the inputShape of the model

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you! I'll get to work to change the shape of the element and try again. Thank you so much, I was stuck at that point and I couldn't figure out how to bypass that.

Comment: The number of possibilites are C(3,1) * C(3,1) * 3! = 27. So there are 27 shapes possible.